# Проверка формы с дополнительными иконками

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Подскажите пожалуйста где ошибка в коде?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <form role="form" id="loginForm" >
      <fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="sex"></label>
    <select class="form-control" id="sex">
      <option>Herr</option>
      <option>Frau</option>
          </select>
    </fieldset>
 <div class="form-group" id="div-firstName">
  <label for="firstName" class="control-label">Vorname</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status" placeholder="z.b. Mustername">
<span class="textCheck" id="firstNameCheck"></span>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group" id="div-lastName">
  <label for="lastName" class="control-label">Nachname</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="z.b. Mustermann">
  <span class="textCheck" id="emailCheck"></span>
 </div>
 <button type="submit" id="btn" class="btn btn-success" onclick="">Speichern</button>
    </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery first, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#loginForm").each(function(){
        var form = $(this),
        btn = $(this).find('#btn')
        firstName = $(this).find('#firstName'),
        lastName = $(this).find('#lastName'),
        divFirstName = $(this).find('#div-firstName'),
        divLastName = $(this).find('#div-lastName');

        function checkInput(){
          if (firstName != "" || firstName != " "){
            divFirstName.addClass('has-success ').removeClass('has-error');
          }
          else {
            divFirstName.addClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');}
          if (lastName != "" || lastName != " "){
            divLastName.addClass('has-success').removeClass('has-error');
          }
          else {
            divLastName.addClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');}
        }
      });
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Не нужно копировать и вставлять текст. Опишите проблему подробно. Что сами уже сделали? Что желаете получить от реализации?

Comment: Владимир, Вопрос от пользователя "Подскажите пожалуйста где ошибка в коде?" И как вы собираетесь ее найти? Не нужно лишних слов, когда есть пример кода. Все понятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Рекомендация:**

Воспользуйтесь плагином http://jqueryvalidation.org/

**Ответ на ваш вопрос:**

1. после

   > btn = $(this).find('#btn')

   отсутствует запятая.
2. Объявление функции внутри итератора (перезапись), в примере отсутствует вызов функции.
3. Итератор по #loginForm. ID должны быть уникальными, воспользуйтесь атрибутом class
4. Убрать пробел

   > .addClass('has-success ')
5. А если 2 пробела?

   > firstName != "" || firstName != " "

Воспользоваться $.trim

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ! Не могли бы вы показать в примере "Объявление функции внутри итератора (перезапись)"?

Comment: У вас в примере checkInput объявлен и не используется, зачем эта функция? Валидировать нужно при изменении полей, а не на document ready.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду использование функции $('form').validate()?? Или каким ещё образом можно вызывать функцию при изменении формы не отправляя её через submit??